# Is using ZeroMQ (or another message queue) a good idea to implement networking in a real-time mobile game?

Tags: networking, udp, message-queue, zeromq

I'm going to implement a mobile game for Android and iOS in which each players' actions need to be broadcasted to other nearby players (nearby in the game) through a server that checks if the actions are permitted. The requirement is that the other players need to be notified about these actions as soon as possible. The actions don't need to be delivered in the order of sending, but the delivery should be reliable.

I'm considering using ZeroMQ to implement that. Nearby players could subscribe to the the same topic and publish/consume messages that contain other player's actions. Using a message queue seems to be very attractive compared to implementing the communication using some kind of RPC. I have the following doubts though:

- Would ZeroMQ work well over a cellular network which isn't very
  reliable?
- ZeroMQ doesn't support sending messages using UDP, only
  TCP. I don't require the messages to be received in an order. If a
  message is lost, I'd like the receiver to be able to process the
  messages that followed the lost one without waiting until the lost
  one is resend. Is it possible to achieve that using ZeroMQ?

As an alternative, I was considering using ProtoBuf with Netty for example, with UDP + reliability implemented on top of that. However, this would be more work and I'm not sure if I'd be able to achieve better performance than ZeroMQ which is considered to be great in that matter.

Actually, is UDP communication over the cellular network/Internet a good idea? Wouldn't there be any issues with operator's firewalls, NATs or so? I'm assuming that it should be fine, since the communication is through a public server, not peer to peer.

Is there any fast and reliable message queue that supports UDP?

Comment: Wouldn't that essentially require that players have an externally-accessible IP address to be able to interconnect between them? Devices on a 3G (not to mention residential WiFi) network might be NAT'd. 

A centralized pub/sub with topics per (hashed?) location  would probably be your best bet.

Comment: Why do you think that NAT would be a problem here? It shouldn't be a problem because the connection would be initiated from a client.

Comment: From my experience NAT's on cellular networks will time out a UDP port mapping if it is idle for more than around 60 seconds.  I presume they will also time out an idle TCP port mapping, but it might be allowed to live longer.  Did you end up using ZeroMQ?

Comment: I have a prototype and it works well, but it hasn't been tested heavily.

Comment: I think it could be a nice solution..don't have persistent messages,and in case of failure in sending a message due to network problems,ignore the exception and discard the message or do whatever failover you would like to implement..NAT shouldn't be much of a problem

Comment: How did you eventually design your system? Would be nice to learn about your findings!

Comment: Unfortunately, the project was cancelled and we didn't test it heavily. The prototype worked well, but we didn't spend much time on making it bulletproof, so I can't say much more about these specifics issues.